# Prove/Disprove: Intersection of closures is in closure of intersection and union of interior is in interior of union.

Tags: general-topology, proof-verification

> Prove\Disprove:
>
> 1. $$\overline{A}\cap\overline{B}\subseteq \overline{A\cap B}$$
> 2. $$int(A)\cup int(B)\subseteq int(A\cup B)$$

1. $A=(1,2)$, $B=(2,3)$ $\Rightarrow$ $\overline{A}=[1,2],\overline{B}=[2,3]$

$$2\in \overline{A}\cap \overline{B}, \text{ but } 2\notin \overline{A\cap B}=\emptyset$$

2. Let \begin{align}
   x\in int(A)\cup int(B)&\Rightarrow x\in int(A) \vee x\in int(B)\\
   &\Rightarrow x\in A\setminus \partial(A) \vee x\in B\setminus \partial(B)\\
   &\Rightarrow x\in A\cup B\setminus  (\partial(A)\cup  \partial(B))=int(A\cup B)
   \end{align}and therefore 
   $$int(A)\cup int(B)\subseteq int(A\cup B)$$

Are the above steps correct?

Comment: @MYUSERNAMEISALIE yes, it was edited

Answer (score 1):

The first counterexample is (now) correct.
In the second proof you made a mistake in the last line, namely:
$$A\setminus \partial (A) \cup B\setminus \partial (B) \not \subseteq A\cup B \setminus ( \partial (A) \cup  \partial (B) ) \neq int(A\cup B)$$
(e.g. consider $x=2$ and $A=[1,3]$ and $B=[2,3]$)

Instead it would be easier to consider the definition $$x \in int(A) \iff \exists S \subseteq A: S \text{ open and } x \in S$$
For such an $S$ of course also $S \subseteq A \cup B$ holds.

Comment: So from $x\in int(A)\vee x\in int(B)$ we can say that $\exists S\subseteq A\cup B  \text{ and }  x\in S$ and therefore $x\in int(A\cup B)$

Comment: @ctst Wait a sec...$$A\setminus \partial (A) \cup B\setminus \partial (B)  \subseteq A\cup B \setminus ( \partial (A) \cup  \partial (B) )$$ is true I think. The inequality you wrote after it is right though.

Comment: @gbox You can even say from $x \in int(A) \lor x \in int(B)$ follows $\exists S \subseteq A \lor S \subseteq B$ with $x \in S$ and $S open$, therefore $S \subseteq A \cup B$.

Comment: @ArghyaChakraborty My example was bad in this case. Consider instead $x=2 \in A=[1,3], B=[2,4]$. Obviously $x \in int(A)$ but $x \in \partial B$, hence $x \not\in \subseteq A\cup B \setminus ( \partial (A) \cup  \partial (B) )$

Comment: Just too good...+1